# How do I have my notification perform action onclick?

Tags: android

The default notification click behavior is lunching the activity, but I want to show a toast or call a method instead. How do I do that?

```
//**cleareble notification**//
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, getIntent(),
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
            .setContentTitle("HELLO world")
            .setContentText("PLEASE CHECK WE HAVE UPDATED NEWS")
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setTicker("ticker message")
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).build();
    //noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
```

Comment: You need an activity to show your Toast

Comment: how do I launch some other activity instead of Main?

Comment: [Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) is a very good tutorial on Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this link in the Android developper site [Building a Notification](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html)

Basically you create a PendingIntent and use setContentIntent method of your Notification.Builder.

Look at section **Define the Notification's Action** and **Set the Notification's Click Behavior**

Comment: Did you try this?